# Multiple picture box collision using ".Bounds.IntersectsWith"

Tags: vb.net

I have created a subroutine for collision between picture boxes. 
I have 3 different colours, each with 10 corresponding picture boxes 
(which totals 30 picture boxes).

Ideally I would like it so when the red picture boxes collide with purple or yellow picture boxes, my sub routine executes. Same with purple and yellow.

Here is my code:

```
Public Sub PurpCollision()
  '
  For Each PictureBox In PurpList
    Collide = False
    If purpPoint1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PictureBox.Bounds) And chkHealth.Checked = False Then
      Collide = True
    Else
      Collide = False
    End If
```

However I am struggling with this section

> purpPoint1.Bounds.IntersectsWith(PictureBox.Bounds)`

How can I set it to list 10 picture boxes, 
and if they intersect with picture boxes from YellowList or Red List collide is true?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [List(Of T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx), you could have a list for each color and then check for collision on the colors you want.

Comment: How would I use List(OfT)? I looked at the link but its really confusing, I do apologise!

Comment: You should also turn Option Explicit On. Substracting Booleans like "chkHealth.Checked - False" is a bit weird.

Comment: "chkHealth.Checked - False" is meant to be an equals which I have corrected. At the moment I'm just trying to get it all working, thanks anyway though

Comment: I'm guessing you are getting an error message on that line, right? Can you tell us what the error is please?